# Chart js dataset label not showing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, chart.js

I'm trying now `chart.js version 3.6` but I got a problem that the dataset label is not showing.

I tried this, but with no avail

```js
    const labels: string[] = [];
    const sold: number[] = [];
    const released: number[] = [];

    for (const d of r.data) {
        labels.push(d.date);
        sold.push(d.sold);
        released.push(d.released);
    }

    const quarterChart = new Chart('quarterGraphCanvas', {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels,
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: 'Sold Amount',
                    data: sold,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'red',
                },
                {
                    label: 'Released Amount',
                    data: released,
                    fill: false,
                    borderColor: 'blue',
                },
            ],
        },
        options: {
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
            },
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                },
            },
        },
    });

    quarterChart.render();
```

The label `Sold Amount` and `Released Amount` is not showing.
What options I missed?

Comment: What do you mean they are not showing, where isn't it showing because they are used in multiple spots

Comment: The chart render without problems when i try with your config, https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html. Please help to add the data to reproduce.

Comment: @LeeLenalee I mean the labels of the dataset is not showing. In version 2 that labels is showing on the top.

Comment: @huy the data is just a simple object, with a `date string`, and numbers for the other property `sold` and `released`

Comment: Seems to be working fine, so only thing I can think of is that you are setting the default of the legend to false somewhere: https://jsfiddle.net/Leelenaleee/ve02q7ja/

Comment: @LeeLenalee the problem was because of the integration, I just pick few controllers to register. I ended up using this import, `import Chart from 'chart.js/auto'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the chart.js integration, I only select a few controllers I thought I only needed, and come up with this.

```js
  Chart.register(
    LinearScale,
    CategoryScale,
    LineElement,
    LineController,
    PointElement
  );
```

And was fixed using

```js
Chart.register(...regiserables);
```

But I settled with

```js
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
```

And completely remove the `Chart.register`.